# Python - checking if a string is in a list and executing specific code for it

Tags: python, list, command-line-interface, user-input

I would like to make a "command handling" system so you can type a command like "/disconnect" in the terminal and it executes code for disconnecting the client program from the server. Or /connect and it connects to it. This would be done by getting the user input and checking if it's in a list of available commands but how do I then execute the code for that specific command? I don't want to do it like this:

```
if input == "/disconnect":
  #code for disconnecting
elif input == "/connect"
  #code for connecting
...
```

because it is clunky and it would be a massive `if else` wall at the end.

The part about creating a list of commands and checking if the user input is in the list I can set up, but I don't know how to do the "executing the code" part.

I did it like the above example when having only those two commands but as I want to expand the command list I also want to rewrite this first as to be more efficient down the line.

Comment: you can make a dictionary of functions: `{'/disconnect': disconnect, '/connect': connect}.get(inpt, not_found)()` (where `disconnect`/`connect`/`not_found` are functions). You can also use [`match`/`case`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) or stick with your `if`/`elif`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this you can create a dict whose keys are the user inputs and values are functions either declared above or imported from some other file

```
def connect(args):
    print('im doing something')
    # code

def disconnect(args):
    print('im doing another thing')
    # code

operations = {
    '/connect': connect,
    '/disconnect': disconnect,
    # /something_else: external_function
}

## USAGE
user_function = '/connect'
sample_args = {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'}
operations[user_function](sample_args)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary with the string as a key and a function as a value

```
actions = {
  "/disconnect": disconnectfunc,
  "/connect": connectfunc
}

actions[input]()
```

You could also use lambda functions for the function

Answer (score 1):

If you're not comfortable with the dictionary approach, then don't forget you can easily break things out into functions and retain the `elif` approach. This maintains readability of the if-elif block with only a minor change to your proposed approach.

```py
def do_connect():
   ...

def do_disconnect():
   ...

def do_unknown():
  ...
```

```py
if input == '/connect':
  do_connect()
elif input == '/disconnect':
  do_disconnect()
else:
  do_unknown()
```

Comment: Just like the dictionary approach this is also a great idea. Thanks!